# The Verification between email addresses function will not work

Tags: javascript, forms, function, validation

I want the user to verify his email address in the "email2" field and in case he has entered the wrong email address the function returns an error message and corrects his email address from the "email" field. This function returns no error but also does not work, ie does not report an error message when email addresses differ. I'm asking for help.

```
<html>

<script>
function validateForm() {

    var x = document.forms["contactform"]["email"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("E-mail is empty");
        return false;
    }

    var x = document.forms["contactform"]["email2"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("Verification E-mail is empty");
        return false;

        if(email != email2){
                // Display the error message
                document.getElementById("emailMismatch").style.display="inline";
                alert("Email address does not match");
                return false;
            }else{
                document.getElementById("emailMismatch").style.display="none";
            }
    }
}
</script>

<body>
    <form name="contactform" method="post">
        <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30" placeholder="E-mail contact person" title="The e-mail must be in the format, example: primer@email.com ">

        <input  type="text" name="email2" maxlength="80" size="30" placeholder="Verify E-mail address" title="The e-mail must be in the format, example: primer@email.com ">

        <input type="submit" value="Send" style="border:1px solid #000000"> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are missing a `}` to terminate the second IF so the third  IF is inside the second and therefore never runs because it is after a `return` :)

Comment: What do you mean, everyone `}` is available, check again.

Comment: You just added the missing `}`

Comment: @Gordon But in the wrong place :)

Comment: Just so you're aware, everyone can see the history of the question ( at https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68952615/revisions) so please don't try to pretend the `}` was always there, it won't work. If you made a typo, just admit to it and move on

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `}` to terminate the second IF so the third IF is inside the second and therefore never runs because it is after a return :)

```
<script>
function validateForm() {

    var x = document.forms["contactform"]["email"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("E-mail is empty");
        return false;
    }

    var x = document.forms["contactform"]["email2"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("Verification E-mail is empty");
        return false;

    } <-- !!!!!!!!!!!!! THIS WAS MISSING  !!!!!!!!!!!!

    if(email != email2){
        // Display the error message
        document.getElementById("emailMismatch").style.display="inline";
        alert("Email address does not match");
        return false;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("emailMismatch").style.display="none";
    }
#} <-- THIS WAS IN THE WRONG PLACE REMOVE IT
}
</script>
```

Comment: I get it, but when I swapped places to `}`, it still doesn't work, the function is not executed and does not display an `alert("Email address does not match");`

Comment: Doesn't work is not a very helpful description. Please be specific

Comment: function is not executed and does not display an `alert("Email address does not match");`

Comment: PS There is no `alert ("verify e-mail");` in the code you showed us

Comment: sorry, `alert("Email address does not match");`

Comment: There is no element with a id of `emailMismatch` maybe the js is crashing! Are you looking at the browsers debugger? F12

Answer (score 0):

You defined a variable named x to hold email input values, then you do comparison with email and email2 variable, which are not defined.

```js
function validateForm() {

    var email = document.forms["contactform"]["email"].value;
    if (email == "") {
        alert("E-mail is empty");
        return false;
    }

    var verificationEmail = document.forms["contactform"]["email2"].value;
    if (verificationEmail == "") {
        alert("Verification E-mail is empty");
        return false;

    } <-- !!!!!!!!!!!!! THIS WAS MISSING  !!!!!!!!!!!!

    if(email != verificationEmail){
        // Display the error message
        document.getElementById("emailMismatch").style.display="inline";
        alert("Email address does not match");
        return false;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("emailMismatch").style.display="none";
    }
}
```

Comment: actually this is not an answer, you better write it under the first post as a comment.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.